# How is the bodyCRC value calculated on an ApexClass?

Tags: apex

How is the bodyCRC value calculated on an ApexClass?

I am trying to get a better understanding of the bodyCRC value so I can assess complexity in the code base.

The Apex documentation states it is a double and the description says

> The CRC (cyclic redundancy check) of the class or trigger file.

bodyCrc

I created a simple class.

```
public with sharing class Simple {
    public Simple() {}

    public void foo(){
        System.debug('foo');
    }
}
```

I then queried the apex Class via SOQL

```
SELECT bodyCRC FROM ApexClass WHERE name = 'Simple';
```

The value of BodyCRC 224,209,661.

```
I modified the class again by adding an "if" statement.

public with sharing class Simple {
    public Simple() {}

    public void foo(){
        Boolean flag = true;
        if(flag){
            System.debug('foo');
        }else{
            System.debug('bar');
        }

    }
}
```

The value of BodyCRC this time is 2,831,042,086

I understand that as complexity is added to the code, the CRC number grows but how that number is calculated is a mystery to me at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A CRC is essentially an old-school hashing algorithm. It allows you to detect if changes have occurred in the file, even if those changes are only capitalization or spacing changes. It says nothing about the complexity of the file (e.g. number of methods, etc). You can read more about [CRC on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) or elsewhere. If you want the complexity of a file, consider using [PMD Apex](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.5.7/pmd-apex/rules/index.html), which can calculate the [cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) of a method or class in order to suggest areas that can be optimized. I don't think the documentation says exactly what BodyCRC is, but based on the output, I expect it is a CRC-32 implementation (meaning, the CRC is calculated in a 32-bit number, and will eventually overflow back to a small number).